# How to avoid pandas extract bringing partial match

Tags: python, pandas, extract

**Scenario:-**

I have a Dataframe as follows

full_sentence

Baggage
age

a list of key words

key_words = [ 'age' ,'man' ]

**Objective:-**

I need to see if the word "age" [ individually ] exists in this column and if it exists make that as a separate column

**Desired output :-**

full_sentence  |   found_word

Baggage        |    NaN
age            |    age

**Command Used:-**

Dataframe.str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(key_words)),flags=re.IGNORECASE,expand=False).astype(str)

**Output with Mismatch**

full_sentence  |   found_word

Baggage        |    age
age            |    age

**Clarification:-**
It seems, extract is doing a partial match of the string as well. Can it be made to extract only if the whole word matches.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex match to `r'^({})$'.format(r'|'.join(key_words))`. `^` in regex means start of line/string and `$` means end of line/string. You should also change to raw strings with `r''` as above for regex patterns.

See [the Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or [the Python2 regex docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot mVChr. Appreciate your quick response

Comment: This actually does not extract the exact word and does not find a match. I think the regex is considering the values appended as a full pattern to search or it looks for the beginning of a line . Is there a suggestion

Comment: The below has solved my problem. Posting it for the befit of all .                                  
-----------------------------------------------
Dataframe['full_sentence'] = Dataframe.tran_desc.str.extract(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(key_words)),flags=re.IGNORECASE,expand=False).astype(str)
---------------------------------------------------                                                                      
 " \b"  applies a boundary for the  search word that is substituted by the format function.